# How to diagnose a sharp, sudden increase in the frequency with which processes enter the D ("uninterruptible sleep") state

Tags: performance, debugging, troubleshooting, sleep

The Linux cluster I work on recently started getting frozen for a few minutes at a time.  I've determined that the reason for this behavior is that processes are very frequently landing in the D ("uninterruptible sleep") state, and staying there for lengthy stretches of time.

Unfortunately, the behavior is difficult to reproduce at will.  Typically, if a command lands in the D state for several minutes before completing, and I repeat the exact same command immediately, the second time around the command completes instantly.

No single executable is responsible for this behavior.  It seems that just about any Unix command is susceptible: `ls`, `grep`, `wc`, `find`, `git`, `vim`, you name it.

Also, the same behavior is affecting all the nodes in the cluster.

Given this pattern, I figure that there must be some problem with the storage system that all the nodes share.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to go beyond this hunch.

Fortunately (I guess), when a command lands in the D state, it remains there for 5-10 minutes.  I figure that this should give me plenty of time for investigating the situation, and hopefully getting more details on what is going on.

My question is: given the PID of a process in the D state, what commands can I run to gather more information on what is happening?

**IMPORTANT:** At the moment, I am primarily interested in *diagnosis*.  In particular, I am not interested in, say, fixing the problem by restarting the cluster, since this won't tell me how to prevent the same situation from arising again.

P.S. If there is a better SE site for this question than Unix & Linux SE, I'll be more than happy to migrate this question; please just let me know.

Comment: What about starting with the WCHAN info given by the *ps* command. If not eloquent enough then what about stracing (strace -p) ?

Answer (score 1):

You say you are running in a cluster. Maybe you are using a file system that spans across multiple computers using the network? That is usually the culprit when a process just stops working for *a little while* (i.e. the I/O has to complete because you are executing Kernel code).

I think your best bet is to get a stack trace of the waiting processes, which is done this way:

```
$ sudo su -
# echo w > /proc/sysrq-trigger
# dmesg -T | less -S
```

The `less` command is optional, of course.

Then look at that stack trace. It is likely to include calls to your network based file system(s) such as `nfs3_proc_getattr` if you are using NFS.

Another solution is to run `gdb -p <pid>`, but there can be permission issues with that command line option if you do not own the process or the debug mode is turned off. If you can start gdb that way, try a `where` once you get the command prompt. That also gives you the stack trace. I have never tried to get such while a process is in `D` state so it may not actually work.

I do not have any good solution if you need to be able to edit those files from any computer. Otherwise, maybe something like HFS would work better for you. That's similar to a network based file system, only it copies the files locally so when you access the files, it's on the very computer you're on and your command can continue to be fast all the time.

**Final thought:** I have had processes get 100% stuck because of NFS. I can't even `kill -9` them. The only way to get rid of them is to reboot. Again, this is because the process is currently in Kernel space and the kernel cannot safely remove such a process. It has to wait for it to go back to user mode and at that point it can receive the signals as sent by `kill`. This is why I have not used that file system in ages. It's not worth it. If I turn off a VM before I correctly unmounted that NFS, it's toast. (Restarting the VM won't restore the old NFS mount point.)